# get aws lambda to start transcribe job with filename without extension

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-transcribe

I have a lambda function which will start a transcribe job when an object is put into the s3 bucket. I am having trouble getting setting the transcribe job to be the file name without the extension; also the file is not putting into the correct prefix folder in S3 bucket for some reason, here's what I have:

```
import json
import boto3
import time
import os
from urllib.request import urlopen

transcribe = boto3.client('transcribe')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    if event:
        file_obj = event["Records"][0]
        bucket_name = str(file_obj['s3']['bucket']['name'])
        file_name = str(file_obj['s3']['object']['key'])
        s3_uri = create_uri(bucket_name, file_name)
        job_name = filename

        print(os.path.splitext(file_name)[0])

        transcribe.start_transcription_job(TranscriptionJobName = job_name,
                                           Media = {'MediaFileUri': s3_uri},
                                           MediaFormat =  'mp3',
                                           LanguageCode = "en-US",
                                           OutputBucketName = "sbox-digirepo-transcribe-us-east-1",
                                           Settings={
                                            # 'VocabularyName': 'string',
                                            'ShowSpeakerLabels': True,
                                            'MaxSpeakerLabels': 2,
                                            'ChannelIdentification': False
                                        })
        while Ture:
            status = transcribe.get_transcription_job(TranscriptionJobName=job_name)
            if status["TranscriptionJob"]["TranscriptionJobStatus"] in ["COMPLETED", "FAILED"]:
                break
            print("Transcription in progress")
            time.sleep(5)

        s3.put_object(Bucket = bucket_name, Key="output/{}.json".format(job_name), Body=load_)
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Transcription job created!')
    }

def create_uri(bucket_name, file_name):
    return "s3://"+bucket_name+"/"+file_name
```

the error i get is

```
[ERROR] BadRequestException: An error occurred (BadRequestException) when calling the StartTranscriptionJob operation: 1 validation error detected: Value 'input/7800533A.mp3' at 'transcriptionJobName' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: ^[0-9a-zA-Z._-]+
```

so my desired output should have the **TranscriptionJobName** value to be 7800533A for this case, and the result OutputBucketName to be in s3bucket/output. any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The `TranscriptionJobName` argument is a friendly name for your job and is pretty limited based on the regex. You're passing it the full object key, which contains the prefix `input/`, but `/` is a disallowed character in the job name. You could just split out the file name portion in your code:

```
job_name = file_name.split('/')[-1]
```

I put a full example of uploading media and starting an AWS Transcribe job on [GitHub](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/6ff2068156ee2224c620bdef8941aadefad713fb/python/example_code/transcribe/transcribe_basics.py#L306) that puts all this in context.